# Add new layers and restore training from checkpoint in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a model with TensorFlow, and the training time cost me weeks. Now, I want to add new layer to the current model and continue training based on the trained weights. However, if I restore checkpoint an error like `"xxx not found in checkpoint"` will occur.

So how can I restore from checkpoint to a modified model in TensorFlow?

Comment: Can't you just load the meta graph, load the variables in a session and then continue building the graph after the session has been created?